# PHP / HTML remember selected value after submit

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I know there are many questions ask about this one, but I tried a lot from here and for some reason, they did't work for me.

I populate the list from mysqli.:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="formCountries[]" size="5" id="keuzeproduct">
  <option value="keuze1" disabled selected="selected[]" multiple="multiple">Selecteer Product</option>
  <?php
       $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Id, Product FROM metingen group by Product order by Product";
       $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
       while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $rows["Product"];?>" ><?php echo $rows["Product"]; ?></option>
          <?php } ?>
       </select>
```

How can I get it so the selected one stays selected after submit?

Comment: have you tried submitting the form data using ajax.

Comment: You should really post the code you used to remember values that didn't work so people can help. In your PHP you have the value that has been selected, "just" return it back to the form and check in every `<option>`s iteration if that value is the same as the iterations value. If so, select that option

Answer (score 0):

Get the value that has been selected and pass it to `$selected_product`
and check with every option you are adding.
This should solve your case

```
   <select multiple="multiple" name="formCountries[]" size="5" id="keuzeproduct">
            <option value="keuze1" disabled selected="selected[]" multiple="multiple">Selecteer Product</option>
            <?php
                $selected_product = $your_value_here; //get the selected product from the database on load
                $is_selected  = "";
                $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Id, Product FROM metingen group by Product order by Product";
                $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
                   while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
                      if($selected_product == $rows["Product"]){
                         $is_selected = "selected";
                      }
                    ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rows["Product"];?>" <?php echo $is_selected; ?>><?php echo $rows["Product"]; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i copyed your code in my script but does'nt do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the option generation with a function:

```
function makeOption($value)
{
    echo "<option value=\"$value\"";
    if(isset($_POST['formCountries']) && in_array($value, $_POST['formCountries']))
        echo ' selected="selected"';
    echo ">$value</option>";
}
```

Use it in while loop:

```
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) )
    makeOption($rows["Product"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpy you can do like this for the option script:

```
<option value="<?php echo $rows["Product"];?>" <?=$rows['Product']=='//your val'?"selected":""?>><?php echo $rows["Product"]; ?></option>
                  <?php } ?>
```